# Copy from specific worksheet from closed Workbook. Values but not formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a tool to make my work go quicker.
What i want to do is basically.
Take a customers Excel Workbook and Compare it to our Workbook.

The customers Workbook is filled with formulas and VLOOKUPS etc etc.
And i want to copy that with my Workbook tool to a new sheet in that workbook and ONLY get the value and not formulas from certain columns. (Columns M;N;O;P)

Ive managed to do the copy and paste but cant get the paste only values to work.
And i want the formulas gone to make the comparison macro work easier.

This is what i got so far, anyone able to help?

```
Sub getData()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse to Danfoss Open Orders.", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
OpenBook.Sheets(8).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
OpenBook.Close False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With Worksheets(2).Columns("O:O").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When opening a new workbook, it will become the ActiveWorkbook, which means unspecific collections like `Sheets` will be switching from the current workbook, to the new workbook. Which will cause unintended effects. I suggest always including the parent workbook when using those collections, like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(...` (and the same with the `Worksheets` collection)

Comment: To turn formulas into values, you can do it very simply: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).UsedRange: .Value = .Value`. This avoids using the clipboard, which speeds up your code.